# Is it possible to animate position of flex items when items are removed/added?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to display items in a container- the items snap to their new positions when items are removed/added. Is there anyway to smoothly transition between the states? Transitions between multiple lines is desired and items can be of variable width. I'm using angular JS to add/remove items.

I haven't been able to come up with a working solution. Any ideas?

[Plunker here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/W2rALKPvxpMCBC0R0AWf?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about angularJS, but you could do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/H9mvd/5/

using transitions. To remove an element, first you'd change the width, margins etc. to 0, and then remove the item on the 'transitionEnd' event:

```
$(this).css({
    'margin-left': '0',
    'margin-right': '0',
    width: '0'
}).on('transitionend', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

And for adding elements, insert the new element with the style attribute such that width, margins etc. are 0. Then remove these from `style` so that the element gets transitioned to it's proper size:

```
container.append('<div style="margin-left:0;margin-right:0;width:0;"></div>');

setTimeout(function(){
    // needs placing in a timeout so that
    // the CSS change will actually transition
    // (CSS changes made right after inserting an
    // element into the DOM won't get transitioned)

    container.children().last().css({
        'margin-left': '',
        'margin-right': '',
        width: ''
    });
},0);
```

There are 'jumps' in position when adding/removing elements because the flexbox is set with `justify-content: space-around;`, so adding/removing an element (even one with zero width) will cause the 'space' between elements to be redistributed. I think it'd be fairly tricky to work around this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very detailed and easy to understand. Unfortunately it seems what I was really interested in was exactly this problem that would be tricky to get around.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is, 
test & try it using animation CSS : http://plnkr.co/edit/VnFTz5VKDJIjFIJ6YBwG?p=preview

```
div.ng-scope {max-width:15em;overflow:hidden;animation:deploy 2s;}
@keyframes deploy {
  from {
    max-width:0;
  }
  to {
    max-width:15em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for adding items, but not removing or multi-line transitions- and there is still a jump in the position when an item is added (most notable when there is only one item already in the row).

Comment: See it as an hint, you have to make your scenari through adding/removing classes , using javascript or CSS transition and or animation. For instance before removing an element , give it a reverse animation. Sure, justify-content remains a pain still :)