# Hiding/Adding element with jquery and transitioning the rest? (maybe with css?)

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I'm not sure if this is possible.
What I have today are 5 DIV's and after clicking a number above them, the jQuery will check for the number clicked and `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` the number of boxes.

What I want to do is that when the boxes are moving around (because of the `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-around`) they have smooth `transition`.

I've tried to do it with the css transition but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me please?

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0k1xj3d5/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="num" rel="1">1</div>
    <div class="num" rel="2">2</div>
    <div class="num" rel="3">3</div>
    <div class="num" rel="4">4</div>
    <div class="num" rel="5">5</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
    <div class="box-4"></div>
    <div class="box-5"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

[class^=box] {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.num {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.num').on('click', function(){
    var quant = $(this).attr('rel');

    for(var i=1; i<=5 ;i++){
      if(i <= quant){
        if(!$('.box-' + i).is(':visible')){
          $('.box-' + i).fadeIn();
        } 
      } else {
        $('.box-' + i).fadeOut();
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to animate position of flex items when items are removed/added?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467209/is-it-possible-to-animate-position-of-flex-items-when-items-are-removed-added)

Comment: Sorry, but this other question didn't answer it completely, they still didn't find a way to add the element and transition the other ones.

Comment: @William what kind of transition do you want exactly? Because you already have the fading transition using jQuery.

Comment: I want a transition that will smoothly move the boxes to the new place. Like when I have 4 boxes and want it to be 5, the four already there will smoothly move left so the 5th will have enough space to fade in. And also when some fade out, like I have 5 boxes and click to have only 2, so 3 of them will fade out and the other 2 will smoothly move right to the new position. All according to the new flex position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way — https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/qgyeay0v/10/:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="num" rel="1">1</div>
    <div class="num" rel="2">2</div>
    <div class="num" rel="3">3</div>
    <div class="num" rel="4">4</div>
    <div class="num" rel="5">5</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper__item wrapper__item_shown">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__item wrapper__item_shown">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__item wrapper__item_shown">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__item wrapper__item_shown">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__item wrapper__item_shown">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.wrapper__item {
    -webkit-flex: 0.00001;
    flex: 0.00001;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.wrapper__item_shown {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.num {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.num').on('click', function(){
    var quant = $(this).attr('rel');
    var $wrapperItems = $('.wrapper__item');

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var $wrapperItem = $wrapperItems.eq(i - 1);

        if (i <= quant) {
            $wrapperItem.addClass('wrapper__item_shown');
        } else {
            $wrapperItem.removeClass('wrapper__item_shown');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to use this `flex: 0.00001;` technique before but with no success.

Comment: Transitions and animations are tricky business, each line of code is important =).